# AG Grid - Sorting a column with key and not Value

Tags: ag-grid

i am searching for an opportunity to sort a column with key and not the shown value and i don't find the approach to do this.

I am loading data like this:

```
[{key: 1, name: 'Microsoft'}, {key: 2, name: 'Apple'}, {key: 3, 'IBM'}]
```

now the sort is like this for the column:

```
'Apple'
'IBM'
'Microsoft'
```

but i want the sorting like this and no column "key" in the grid:

```
'Microsoft'
'Apple'
'IBM'
```

I think i need to use custom sorting, but didn't understand how to start.

Any help is useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to [so], would you mind sharing your code on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you? also go through how to create [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `comparator` in `columnDefs` like -

```
var columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'Company', 
    field: 'name', 
    comparator: (value1, value2, node1, node2) => node1.data.key - node2.data.key
  }
];
```

Here is the Plunker: [Custom Sorting ag-Grid](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/DUTdkH8uHuF1TJrh)